# wc -l and python line count differ

Tags: python, bash, count, line, wc

I'm wondering why a simple line count using bash is giving me a different number of lines than that computed using python (version 3.6) for the files given [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4t6re556n97pwy/train_en.txt?dl=0) (`train_en.txt`) and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xnztryx736972kx/train_de.txt?dl=0) (`train_de.txt`). In bash, I'm using the command:

```
wc -l train_en.txt
wc -l train_de.txt
```

The outputs are 4520620 and 4520620, respectively.

In python, I'm using the commands:

```
print(sum(1 for line in open('train_en.txt')))
print(sum(1 for line in open('train_de.txt')))
```

The outputs are 4521327 and 4521186, respectively.

When I use the python commands

```
len(open('train_en.txt').read().splitlines())
len(open('train_de.txt').read().splitlines())
```

I get 4521334 and 4521186, respectively (for which the `train_en.txt` results don't match those of the previous python command).

For reference, these are parallel corpora of text produced by concatenating the [Common Crawl](http://www.statmt.org/wmt13/training-parallel-commoncrawl.tgz), [Europarl](http://www.statmt.org/wmt13/training-parallel-europarl-v7.tgz), and [News Commentary](http://www.statmt.org/wmt14/training-parallel-nc-v9.tgz) datasets (in that order) from the [WMT '14 English to German translation task](http://www.statmt.org/wmt14/translation-task.html) and should have the same number of lines.

Comment: With which locale settings? Does running with `LC_ALL=C` exported modify behavior?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server, versjon 7.6, fedora

Comment: What's the output of the `locale` command?

Comment: This throws `UnicodeDecodeError` for me in Python 3.6

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, sorry, the output of `locale` is: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: @JacobIRR, yes, upon exporting `LC_ALL=C`, I get the same error.

Comment: Have you looked at which of those input datasets the issue happens in? If only a subset of them are correctly-encoded UTF-8, it'd be helpful to treat the faulty one(s) individually rather than needing to transform a dataset with content in different character sets mixed together. (Granted, it's not yet confirmed that that's the issue at hand, but it's a pretty good guess).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, looking into it now. Will get back to you shortly.

Comment: (Making it `open('train_de.txt', encoding='utf-8')` will make the Python code less sensitive to `LC_CTYPE`, but doesn't do much for the discrepancy).

Comment: BTW, 4520620 is the correct count of the number of LF characters in the file; Python is presumably realizing that some of those LF characters are part of multi-byte "wide" characters (should the file be parsed as UTF-8), whereas your current locally-installed copy of `wc` is presumably not multi-byte-aware.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195598/discussion-between-vivek-subramanian-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\n`s can be treated as multi-byte characters rather than as an actual `\n`. One can avoid this by using bytestring encoding. The commands

```
print(sum(1 for line in open('train_en.txt', mode='rb')))
print(sum(1 for line in open('train_de.txt', mode='rb')))
len(open('train_en.txt', mode='rb').read().splitlines())
len(open('train_de.txt', mode='rb').read().splitlines())
```

all result in 4520620 (matching the output of `wc -l`), which means that the English and German corpora are parallel as desired.

Thanks to @CharlesDuffy for the help.